# NSAttributedString alignment to particular text

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I m trying to align the attributed text of UILabel with multiple lines as below.
The alignment should be like all the days in chars left align and timings right align. How can i do this .Please suggest.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would break the string into 2 and align the day to right and the time to left. Otherwise you need to calculate each letters width (and the spacing between the letter before and/or after.) Fonts are complex as the glyph itself and its spacing to neighbours are different from letter to letter.

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is someone who found an elegant way to do this.
I also had very similar task and here is how I did it.
I achieved this by breaking the line into two pieces.(what should be aligned left and what should be aligned right)

1. Then on your view create two UILable with the equal widths.

[image]

After that display left side in Keys Label and right side in Values label

Do not forget set Lines to 0

Answer (score -1):

Left align your text.

```
textAlignment = NSTextalignmentLeft
```

Separate each line with "\n" to force a new line

```
 @"Tuesday 9:20\nWednesday 8:40"
```

Comment: Doesn't even attempt to answer the original question